# How to configure Auth LDAP plugin for Dokuwiki

Tags: php, authentication, caching, ldap, dokuwiki

Every time I'm trying to login into dokuwiki with my LDAP credentials I'm getting the error below:
[image]

*However once when I tried to log in with Internet Explorer rather than with Chrome I logged in successfully, but that never happened again.*

Would someone please help me with configuring dokuwiki to authenticate users with LDAP credentials using AuthLDAP plugin.

Please see the content of **conf/local.php** file:

```
$conf['title'] = 'SomeNameOfDokuWiki';
$conf['license'] = '0';
$conf['useacl'] = 1;
$conf['authtype'] = 'authldap';
$conf['passcrypt'] = 'md5';
$conf['superuser'] = 'xander';
$conf['disableactions'] = 'register';
$conf['proxy']['user'] = 'SomeUserName';
$conf['proxy']['pass'] = 'SomeEncryptedPassword';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['server'] = 'ldap://some.local.ip.address.129:389';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['usertree'] = 'ou=Users,dc=example,dc=max,dc=net';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['grouptree'] = 'ou=Groups,dc=xander,dc=max,dc=net';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['userfilter'] = '(&(cn=%{user})(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['groupfilter'] = '(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(gidNumber=%{gid})(memberUID=%{user})))';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['version'] = 3;
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['bindpw'] = 'SomeBindPassword';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['userkey'] = 'cn';
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['debug'] = 1;
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['modPass'] = 0;
```

I'm sure that following queries are correct (I checked them through phpldapadmin):

```
(&(cn=%{user})(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))
(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(gidNumber=%{gid})(memberUID=%{user})))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are missing this.

```
$conf['plugin']['authldap']['binddn'] = 'CN=ad user with enough rights to see other accounts,CN=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com';
```